# SaS Scenario Generation

Tags: sas

Can someone please help with the scenario below?  I am very new to SaS and am not sure how to get this to work?

Simulate 200 observations from the following linear model:

```
Y = alpha + beta1 * X1 + beta2 * X2 + noise
```

where:

• `alpha=1, beta1=2, beta2=-1.5`

• `X1 ~ N(1, 4), X2 ~ N(3,1), noise ~ N(0,1)`

I have tried this code but not sure its completely accurate:

```
 DATA ONE;
 alpha = 1;
 beta1 = 2;
 beta2 = -1.5;
 RUN;

 DATA CALC;
    SET ONE;
   DO i = 1 to 200;
 Y=alpha+beta1*X1+beta2*X2+Noise;
 X1=Rannor(1);
 X2=rannor(3);
 Noise=ranuni(0);
  OUTPUT;
  END;

 RUN;

 PROC PRINT DATA=CALC;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look in the SAS help for the topics 
"rannor","ranuni","generating random numbers",...

rannor: generating standard normal distributed RVs.

ranuni: uniform distributed RVs.

The argument in rannor is the seed number, not the expected value.

If N(x,y) in your example means that the random variable is normally distributed with expected value x and standard deviation y (or do you mean the variance???) then the code could be (have a look on the changed order of the statements; the definition of Y has to be after the definition of the random numbers...):

```
DATA ONE;
 alpha = 1;
 beta1 = 2;
 beta2 = -1.5;
RUN;

DATA CALC;
 SET ONE;
 seed = 1234;
 DO i = 1 to 200;
   X1=1+4*Rannor(seed);
   X2=3+rannor(seed);
   Noise=rannor(seed);
   Y=alpha+beta1*X1+beta2*X2+Noise;
   OUTPUT;
 END;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=CALC;
RUN;
```

There are also variants for generating random numbers, e.g. "call rannor". There are different concepts to deal with seed numbers in SAS. See the SAS help for these topics, e.g. [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202908.htm)